# Web3js fails to import in Vue3 composition api project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, web3js, vite

I've created a brand new project with `npm init vite bar -- --template vue`. I've done an `npm install web3` and I can see my `package-lock.json` includes this package. My `node_modules` directory also includes the `web3` modules.

So then I added this line to `main.js`:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Web3 from 'web3'   <-- This line


createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

And I get the following error:
[image: Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined]

I don't understand what is going on here. I'm fairly new to using `npm` so I'm not super sure what to Google. The errors are coming from `node_modules/web3/lib/index.js`, `node_modules/web3-core/lib/index.js`, `node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js`, and finally `node_modules/util/util.js`. I suspect it has to do with one of these:

1. I'm using Vue 3
2. I'm using Vue 3 Composition API
3. I'm using Vue 3 Composition API SFC `<script setup>` tag (but I imported it in `main.js` so I don't think it is this one)
4. `web3js` is in Typescript and my Vue3 project is not configured for Typescript

But as I am fairly new to JavaScript and Vue and Web3 I am not sure how to focus my Googling on this error. My background is Python, Go, Terraform. Basically the back end of the back end. Front end JavaScript is new to me.

**How do I go about resolving this issue?**

Comment: Wow ok, so I found this comment: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1973#issuecomment-787571499

Comment: But then I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined` with a similar chain of errors...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Option 1: Polyfill Node globals/modules

Polyfilling the Node globals and modules enables the `web3` import to run in the browser:

1. Install the [ESBuild plugins](https://github.com/remorses/esbuild-plugins) that polyfill Node globals/modules:

```bash
npm i -D @esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill
npm i -D @esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill
```

2. Configure [`optimizeDeps.esbuildOptions`](https://vitejs.dev/config/#optimizedeps-esbuildoptions) to use these ESBuild plugins.
3. Configure [`define`](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#define) to replace `global` with `globalThis` (the browser equivalent).

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import GlobalsPolyfills from '@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill'
import NodeModulesPolyfills from '@esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill'

export default defineConfig({
  ⋮
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      2️⃣
      plugins: [
        NodeModulesPolyfills(),
        GlobalsPolyfills({
          process: true,
          buffer: true,
        }),
      ],
      3️⃣
      define: {
        global: 'globalThis',
      },
    },
  },
})
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-web3-demo-ffecex?file=vite.config.ts)

*Note: The polyfills add considerable size to the build output.*

#### Option 2: Use pre-bundled script

`web3` distributes a bundled script at `web3/dist/web3.min.js`, which can run in the browser without any configuration (listed as ["pure js"](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.0/getting-started.html#adding-web3-js)). You could configure a [`resolve.alias`](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#resolve-alias) to pull in that file:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  ⋮
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      web3: 'web3/dist/web3.min.js',
    },

    // or
    alias: [
      {
        find: 'web3',
        replacement: 'web3/dist/web3.min.js',
      },
    ],
  },
})
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-web3-demo-w1lkev?file=vite.config.ts)

*Note: This option produces **469.4 KiB** smaller output than Option 1.*

Comment: You saved my day here! I went with option 1 and it works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks I was having a hard time with this one!

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the `Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined` error by adding this in your vite config

```js
export default defineConfig({
  // ...
  define: {
    'process.env': process.env
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the best solution.

The problem is because you lose `window.process` variable, and process exists only on node, not the browser.

So you should inject it to browser when the app loads.

Add this line to your app:

```
window.process = {
  ...window.process,
};
```