# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call') on build but not dev

Tags: npm, web3js, vite

I am running a `vite.js` app with web3 installed.
When I run the app in dev mode, all works fine but when I run it in production mode (build) it fails with:
`"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')"`.

I can confirm that the error comes from the contract method generated from my ABI:
contract.methods.isOwner(sender)`.call`({from: sender}, function (err, res)

If I comment this line out I wont get the error.

You can reproduce the error by using my test repo:
download my test repo:
https://github.com/nybroe/web3_vite_call_of_undefined/tree/main

follow the readme with repo steps:

**setup:**

1. download the repro
2. navigate to "app"
3. npm install

**dev test (which works)**

1. npm run dev
2. check the console - no errors

**build test (which breaks)**

1. npm run build
2. npm run preview
3. check the console - you will see the following errors: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69021714

I use the option 2

In your `vite.config.js`, add `web3`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  ⋮
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      web3: 'web3/dist/web3.min.js',
    },

    // or
    alias: [
      {
        find: 'web3',
        replacement: 'web3/dist/web3.min.js',
      },
    ],
  },
})
```